# QQplot for discrete distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x, distribution, quantile

I have a set whose samples are discrete values (in particular, the size of a queue over time). Now I'd like to find what distribution they belong to. To achieve this goal I'd act the same way I did for the other quantities, i.e. plotting a qqplot, launching

```
import statsmodels.api as sm 
sm.qqplot(df, dist = 'geom', sparams = (.5,), line ='s', alpha = 0.3, marker ='.')
```

This works if `dist` is not a discrete random variables (e.g. 'exp' or 'norm') and indeed I used to get some results, but when the distribution is discrete (say, 'geom'), I get

```
AttributeError: 'geom_gen' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

I searched on the Internet how to make a qqplot (or something similar) to spot what distribution my samples belong to but I found nothing

Answer (score 0):

Generate a theoretical geometric distribution using scipy.stats.geom, convert the sample and theoretical data using statsmodels' ProbPlot and pass these to statsmodels' qqplot_2samples.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from statsmodels.graphics.gofplots import ProbPlot
from statsmodels.graphics.gofplots import qqplot_2samples

p_theor = 1/4 # The probability we check for
p_sample = 1/5 # The true probability of the sample distribution

# The experimental data
x_sample = stats.geom.rvs(p_sample, size=50)

# The model data
x_theor = stats.geom.rvs(p_theor, size=100)

qqplot_2samples(ProbPlot(x_sample), ProbPlot(x_theor), line='45')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I'm new in Python, therefore I want to ask you, if you don't mind, to tell me if the function that I posted, based on your answer, that (hopefully) plots the QQplot given a sample set is correct

Comment: Where do I make mistakes?

Comment: If you modify your code I would appreciate it very much. I know what Q-Q plots are, my problem is that I don't know Python

Answer (score 0):

```
def discreteQQ(x_sample):

    p_test = np.array([])
    for i in range(0, 1001):
        p_test = np.append(p_test, i/1000)
        i = i + 1

    x_sample = np.sort(x_sample)
    x_theor = stats.geom.rvs(.5, size=len(x_sample))
    ecdf_sample = np.arange(1, len(x_sample) + 1)/(len(x_sample)+1)

    x_theor = stats.geom.ppf(ecdf_sample, p=0.5)

    for p in p_test:
        plt.scatter(np.quantile(x_theor, p), np.quantile(x_sample, p), c = 'blue')

    plt.xlabel('Theoretical quantiles')
    plt.ylabel('Sample quantiles')
    plt.show()
```